# How to split data in parent and child format for adding it to the expandable list-view

Tags: java, android, parent-child, expandablelistview

i am getting data from server like below:

```
 Water-> Drinking Water

 Soil-> All Tests

 Soil-> Chemical Analysis

 Soil-> Field Tests
```

So i want to add it to the expandable list-view and for doing so in need data in parent-childs format like

```
soil->[All Tests, Chemical Analysis, Field Tests] & Water->[Drinking Water, Construction Water] etc
```

that is (parent-string , ArrayList[childs]) format for multiple parents and their respective childs.

**Constructor for the expandable list view is:**

```
public ExpListViewAdapterWithCheckbox(Context context,
                                      ArrayList<ExpListGroupItems> listDataGroup, HashMap<String, List<ExpListChildItems>> listDataChild)
```

As you can see the last parameter is a HashMap with a String for parent and array-list for the respective child items.

Once i get data in this format i can populate the expandable list view.
I am not getting how it can be done.

please help me.

Thanks...